# EAL initialization error on running DPDK sample program

Tags: dpdk

Following error occurs on executing sample program ./basicfwd -c 1 -n 4
I have already set hugepages.

```
EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: No available 16777216 kB hugepages reported
EAL: 1024 hugepages of size 2097152 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found for that size
EAL: No free 524288 kB hugepages reported on node 0
EAL: No available 524288 kB hugepages reported
EAL: FATAL: Cannot get hugepage information.
EAL: Cannot get hugepage information.
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: Error with EAL initialization
```

Please suggest how to resolve this error.

Comment: are there any updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the logs the reason for the error is stated out as `EAL: 1024 hugepages of size 2097152 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found for that size`. This means the 2MB hugepages are not mounted.

There are 2 ways to mount the hugepages

1. using dpdk tool `usertools/dpdk-hugepages.py --setup 1G`
2. manually mount the pages `mount -t hugetlbfs hugetlbfs /path/to/hugepages2M -o pagesize=2M`

All these are clearly covered [getting started dpdk guide](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html). Hence I requested to please read up and follow as stated in the guide.

Comment: Thanks Vipin.Error is solved by using the command to mount hugepages