# Running F-stack DPDK executable - Unsupported Rx multi queue mode 1

Tags: c++, dpdk

I have a C++ program which does lots of stuff, but most importantly it is setup to use F-Stack, which is built on DPDK:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    ff_init(argc, argv);
    ...
}
```

And I run the program like this:

```
sudo ./main --conf /etc/f-stack.conf --proc-type=primary
```

This is the error message I am receiving:

```
virtio_dev_configure(): Unsupported Rx multi queue mode 1
Port0 dev_configure = -22
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: init_port_start failed
```

I have not had this problem before when running this executable on a Centos 8 AWS instance. I am now running this on a Centos 8 Alibaba Cloud instance. So there's possibly some difference when running on Alibaba.

The only other thing I can think of is that there might be a configuration problem. However, I copied `/etc/f-stack.conf` from my AWS instance to Alibaba and updated some IP addresses, nothing else. So nothing significant has changed.

Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

---

**Edit:** here is my `/etc/f-stack.conf` file (without IP addresses included):

```
[dpdk]
# Hexadecimal bitmask of cores to run on.
lcore_mask=1

# Number of memory channels.
channel=4

# Specify base virtual address to map.
#base_virtaddr=0x7f0000000000

# Promiscuous mode of nic, defualt: enabled.
promiscuous=1
numa_on=1

# TX checksum offload skip, default: disabled.
# We need this switch enabled in the following cases:
# -> The application want to enforce wrong checksum for testing purposes
# -> Some cards advertize the offload capability. However, doesn't calculate che                                                                                                 cksum.
tx_csum_offoad_skip=0

# TCP segment offload, default: disabled.
tso=0

# HW vlan strip, default: enabled.
vlan_strip=1

# sleep when no pkts incoming
# unit: microseconds
idle_sleep=0

# sent packet delay time(0-100) while send less than 32 pkts.
# default 100 us.
# if set 0, means send pkts immediately.
# if set >100, will dealy 100 us.
# unit: microseconds
pkt_tx_delay=100

# use symmetric Receive-side Scaling(RSS) key, default: disabled.
symmetric_rss=0

# PCI device enable list.
# And driver options
#pci_whitelist=02:00.0

# enabled port list
#
# EBNF grammar:
#
#    exp      ::= num_list {"," num_list}
#    num_list ::= <num> | <range>
#    range    ::= <num>"-"<num>
#    num      ::= '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
#
# examples
#    0-3       ports 0, 1,2,3 are enabled
#    1-3,4,7   ports 1,2,3,4,7 are enabled
#
# If use bonding, shoule config the bonding port id in port_list
# and not config slave port id in port_list
# such as, port 0 and port 1 trank to a bonding port 2,
# should set `port_list=2` and config `[port2]` section

port_list=0

# Number of vdev.
nb_vdev=0

# Number of bond.
nb_bond=0

# Each core write into own pcap file, which is open one time, close one time if                                                                                                  enough.
# Support dump the first snaplen bytes of each packet.
# if pcap file is lager than savelen bytes, it will be closed and next file was                                                                                                  dumped into.
[pcap]
enable=0
snaplen=96
savelen=16777216
savepath=.

# Port config section
# Correspond to dpdk.port_list's index: port0, port1...
[port0]
addr=<ADDR>
netmask=<NETMASK>
broadcast=<BROADCAST>
gateway=<GATEWAY>

# IPv6 net addr, Optional parameters.
#addr6=ff::02
#prefix_len=64
#gateway6=ff::01

# Multi virtual IPv4/IPv6 net addr, Optional parameters.
#       `vip_ifname`: default `f-stack-x`
#       `vip_addr`: Separated by semicolons, MAX number 64;
#                   Only support netmask 255.255.255.255, broadcast x.x.x.255 no                                                                                                 w, hard code in `ff_veth_setvaddr`.
#       `vip_addr6`: Separated by semicolons, MAX number 64.
#       `vip_prefix_len`: All addr6 use the same prefix now, default 64.
#vip_ifname=lo0
#vip_addr=192.168.1.3;192.168.1.4;192.168.1.5;192.168.1.6
#vip_addr6=ff::03;ff::04;ff::05;ff::06;ff::07
#vip_prefix_len=64

# lcore list used to handle this port
# the format is same as port_list
#lcore_list=0

# bonding slave port list used to handle this port
# need to config while this port is a bonding port
# the format is same as port_list
#slave_port_list=0,1

# Vdev config section
# orrespond to dpdk.nb_vdev's index: vdev0, vdev1...
#    iface : Shouldn't set always.
#    path : The vuser device path in container. Required.
#    queues : The max queues of vuser. Optional, default 1, greater or equal to                                                                                                  the number of processes.
#    queue_size : Queue size.Optional, default 256.
#    mac : The mac address of vuser. Optional, default random, if vhost use phy                                                                                                  NIC, it should be set to the phy NIC's mac.
#    cq : Optional, if queues = 1, default 0; if queues > 1 default 1.
#[vdev0]
##iface=/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/vhost-user0
#path=/var/run/openvswitch/vhost-user0
#queues=1
#queue_size=256
#mac=00:00:00:00:00:01
#cq=0

# bond config section
# See http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/link_bonding_poll_mode_drv_lib.html
#[bond0]
#mode=4
#slave=0000:0a:00.0,slave=0000:0a:00.1
#primary=0000:0a:00.0
#mac=f0:98:38:xx:xx:xx
## opt argument
#socket_id=0
#xmit_policy=l23
#lsc_poll_period_ms=100
#up_delay=10
#down_delay=50

# Kni config: if enabled and method=reject,
# all packets that do not belong to the following tcp_port and udp_port
# will transmit to kernel; if method=accept, all packets that belong to
# the following tcp_port and udp_port will transmit to kernel.
#[kni]
#enable=1
#method=reject
# The format is same as port_list
#tcp_port=80,443
#udp_port=53

# FreeBSD network performance tuning configurations.
# Most native FreeBSD configurations are supported.
[freebsd.boot]
hz=100

# Block out a range of descriptors to avoid overlap
# with the kernel's descriptor space.
# You can increase this value according to your app.
fd_reserve=1024

kern.ipc.maxsockets=262144

net.inet.tcp.syncache.hashsize=4096
net.inet.tcp.syncache.bucketlimit=100

net.inet.tcp.tcbhashsize=65536

kern.ncallout=262144

kern.features.inet6=1
net.inet6.ip6.auto_linklocal=1
net.inet6.ip6.accept_rtadv=2
net.inet6.icmp6.rediraccept=1
net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=0

[freebsd.sysctl]
kern.ipc.somaxconn=32768
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=16777216

net.link.ether.inet.maxhold=5

net.inet.tcp.fast_finwait2_recycle=1
net.inet.tcp.sendspace=16384
net.inet.tcp.recvspace=8192
#net.inet.tcp.nolocaltimewait=1
net.inet.tcp.cc.algorithm=cubic
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_max=16777216
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_max=16777216
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_auto=1
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_auto=1
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_inc=16384
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_inc=524288
net.inet.tcp.sack.enable=1
net.inet.tcp.blackhole=1
net.inet.tcp.msl=2000
net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=0

net.inet.udp.blackhole=1
net.inet.ip.redirect=0
net.inet.ip.forwarding=0
```

---

**Edit 2**: I added `pci_whitelist=[PCIe BDF of NIC]` to config and ran the following command:

[image]

Comment: I actually decided to use the `/etc/f-stack.conf` default instead, to make sure that the copying wasn't the problem. The same error occurs. Yes I can post the config (without IP addresses).

Comment: @DavidCallanan in the conf file there is option of selecting NIC, Can you update the conf file to pick the right NIC via `pci_whitelist=[PCIe BDF of NIC]` and Can you execute `lshw -c net -businfo | grep "[PCIe BDF of NIC]"` update in the question? This will help to narrow down the nic in use. Then we can easily cross-check what part of port_conf is conflict.

Comment: @stackinside Yes, I am building it manually. I'll see if I can add in that patch.

Comment: @DavidCallanan thanks for the update, analyze and narrowed down the cause of the issue and updated as the answer. If you find this useful please accept and upvote.

Comment: @stackinside I am trying that now :) You should have posted your suggestion as an answer yesterday, now it is the same as the other answer.

Comment: @stackinside I am now getting a different error: `Error with EAL initialization`.

Comment: @stackinside Did you delete all your comments? Anyway I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is because of the check for virtio PMD in function `virtio_dev_configure` file `[dpdk root folder]drivers/net/virtio/virtio_ethdev.c`. This can be due to the current Fstack enables `RSS` for better flow distribution over its port-queue pair.

There 2 possible solution to fix the problem is to

1. find the configuration parameter in **f-stack.conf** to disable RSS or
2. change the FSTACK port configuration logic not to use RSS (by editing code).

File: lib/ff_dpdk_if.c
edit: line 627 from `port_conf.rxmode.mq_mode = ETH_MQ_RX_RSS;` to `port_conf.rxmode.mq_mode = ETH_MQ_RX_NONE;` and rebuild the fstack

Note: if you use physical NIC RSS is supported in most of cases. hence there will be no error there.

Comment: Hmmm... it is already set to `ETH_MQ_RX_NONE`.

Comment: in virtio PMD, if it is not set ETH_MQ_RX_NONE, driver initialization fails with `virtio_dev_configure(): Unsupported Rx multi queue mode 1`. Based on the error log, I have disagree the binary in use is using the same. I am happy to debug with over skype to cross check this. I am available now

Comment: You said I also had to change a configuration parameter. Could this be why? Do you know what parameter this is? I need to be available at work so can't skype, but thanks for the offer.

Comment: @DavidCallanan I have suggested 2 options. OPtion 2 is changed is file and recompile fstack. I too have work, since this was easy to debug I mentioned I can be available now.

Comment: It turns out someone else was also trying to fix this problem and logged onto my server and made the change you suggested, which is why it was already set to `ETH_MQ_RX_NONE`. So I just need to make sure I re-build everything correctly, and then I'll let you know if the problem is fixed!

Comment: thanks for update, if it work please accept and upvote to close the question

Comment: I am now getting a different error: `Error with EAL initialization`.

Comment: @DavidCallanan if the current error is solved with the suggestion please accept and upvote to close it, open a new question with new error

Comment: That is a good idea. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: thanks for closing the current question, waiting for the new question to check

Comment: I think this fixed it: [`usertools/dpdk-hugepages.py --setup 1G`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67997471/1541397).

Comment: ok, great good to hear `you and team are out of the issues`

Comment: I just realized: you are the one who answered the question I just linked you. Amazing.

Comment: Happy to hear the issue is resolved from existing question